# Pythonic zipping two lists, differing length, into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, enumerate

I have two lists of strings with different lengths:

```
k = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
v = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',]
dict = {}
```

I want to have the following output:

```
{'a': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'b': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'c': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'd': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'e': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'f': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'g': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',]}
```

The closest I have gotten is this:

```
{key: [key, value] for key, value in zip(k, v)}
```

and

```
(kvalue,vvalue) for kkey, kvalue in enumerate(k) for vkey, vvalue in enumerate(v)
```

The ultimate goal with this is to use the key, value pairs to insert the contained strings into a string in a separate for loop. I'm using Python 3.6.

Pseudocode:

```
for filenames in directory:
    var = 'some string' + each key/value pairing
    print(var)

>>> some string a z
>>> some string a y
>>> some string a x
>>> some string a w
>>> some string b z
>>> some string b y
>>> some string b x
>>> some string b w
>>> some string c z
>>> some string c y
>>> some string c x
>>> some string c w
>>> some string d z
>>> some string d y
>>> some string d x
>>> some string d w
>>> some string e z
>>> some string e y
>>> some string e x
>>> some string e w
>>> some string f z
>>> some string f y
>>> some string f x
>>> some string f w
>>> some string g z
>>> some string g y
>>> some string g x
>>> some string g w
```

Comment: Please never call your variables the names of standard objects, like `dict` or `list`. You will shadow them, and this may lead to mind-boggling bugs were obviously correct code does not work.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question, use [dict.fromkeys()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) :

```
k = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
v = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',]
d = dict.fromkeys(k, v)
```

output:

```
{'a': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'],
 'b': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'],
 'c': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'],
 'd': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'],
 'e': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'],
 'f': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'],
 'g': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w']}
```

For the second part, you actually don't need the first, use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

k = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
v = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',]

out = ['some string {} {}'.format(key, val) for key, val in product(k, v)]
```

output:

```
['some string a z',
 'some string a y',
 'some string a x',
 'some string a w',
 'some string b z',
 'some string b y',
 'some string b x',
 'some string b w',
 'some string c z',
 'some string c y',
 'some string c x',
 'some string c w',
 'some string d z',
 'some string d y',
 'some string d x',
 'some string d w',
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary-comprehension:

```
result = {x: v for x in k}
print(result)
{'a': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'], 'b': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'], 'c': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'], 'd': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'], 'e': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'], 'f': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w'], 'g': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w']}
```

This creates a dictionary with keys `x` from `k` and values `v`.

Comment: Please note that each key shares the same list as a value, so _updating_ `result['a']` will update the value for every other key. One could do `{x: v[:] ...}` to make defensive copies.

Comment: Thanks for that (and the edit). I didn't know that copying is as easy as using `v[:]`.

Comment: Frankly, `[:]`, which is a list slice with all parameters set to default, is a shallow copy; for more difficult cases, module `copy` exists with `deepcopy` function. (Treating structures as immutable is generally even better.)

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary comprehension would do:

```
k = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
v = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',]
print({key: v for key in k})

# {'a': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'b': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'c': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'd': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'e': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'f': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',], 'g': ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong method altogether: `zip` is for corresponding pairs only, giving you `(a z) (b y) (c x)` and so on, without providing the other pairings.

Is there some reason you need to generate this more than once?  If not, this is a job for `itertools.product`, not `zip`.

```
from itertools import product

k = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
v = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w',]

for pair in product(k, v):
    print("some string " + ' '.join(pair))
```

Output:

```
some string a z
some string a y
some string a x
some string a w
some string b z
some string b y
some string b x
some string b w
...
some string g x
some string g w
```